# Upload and parse csv file with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

I'm wondering if anyone with a better understanding of python and gae can help me with this.  I am uploading a csv file from a form to the gae datastore.

```
class CSVImport(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
     csv_file = self.request.get('csv_import')
     fileReader = csv.reader(csv_file)
     for row in fileReader:       
       self.response.out.write(row)
```

I'm running into the same problem that someone else mentions here - http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/bb2d0b1a80ca7ac2/861c8241308b9717

That is, the csv.reader is iterating over each character and not the line.  A google engineer left this explanation:

> The call self.request.get('csv') returns a String. When you iterate over a 
>   string, you iterate over the characters, not the lines. You can see the 
>   difference here:

```
 class ProcessUpload(webapp.RequestHandler): 
   def post(self): 
     self.response.out.write(self.request.get('csv')) 
     file = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sample.csv')) 
     self.response.out.write(file) 

     # Iterating over a file 
     fileReader = csv.reader(file) 
     for row in fileReader: 
       self.response.out.write(row) 

     # Iterating over a string 
     fileReader = csv.reader(self.request.get('csv')) 
     for row in fileReader: 
       self.response.out.write(row)
```

I really don't follow the explanation, and was unsuccessful implementing it.  Can anyone provide a clearer explanation of this and a proposed fix?

Thanks,
August

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer, try this:

```
fileReader = csv.reader(csv_file.split("\n"))
```

Long answer, consider the following:

```
for thing in stuff:
  print thing.strip().split(",")
```

If stuff is a file pointer, each thing is a line. If stuff is a list, each thing is an item. If stuff is a string, each thing is a character.

Iterating over the object returned by csv.reader is going to give you behavior similar to iterating over the object passed in, only with each item CSV-parsed. If you iterate over a string, you'll get a CSV-parsed version of each character.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes a lot more sense to me now.

Comment: I would consider using .splitlines() instead of .split('\n')

Answer (score 8):

I can't think of a clearer explanation than what the Google engineer you mentioned said. So let's break it down a bit.

The Python `csv` module operates on file-like objects, that is a file or something that behaves like a Python file. Hence, csv.reader() expects to get a file object as it's only required parameter.

The `webapp.RequestHandler` request object provides access to the HTTP parameters that are posted in the form. In HTTP, parameters are posted as key-value pairs, e.g., `csv=record_one,record_two`. When you invoke `self.request.get('csv')` this returns the *value* associated with the key csv as a Python string. A Python string is not a file-like object. Apparently, the `csv` module is falling-back when it does not understand the object and simply iterating it (in Python, strings can be iterated over by character, e.g., `for c in 'Test String': print c` will print each character in the string on a separate line).

Fortunately, Python provides a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) class that allows a string to be treated as a file-like object. So (assuming GAE supports StringIO, and there's no reason it shouldn't) you should be able to do this:

```
class ProcessUpload(webapp.RequestHandler): 
   def post(self): 
     self.response.out.write(self.request.get('csv')) 

     # Iterating over a string as a file 
     stringReader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(self.request.get('csv')))
     for row in stringReader: 
        self.response.out.write(row)
```

Which will work as you expect it to.

**Edit** I'm assuming that you are using something like a `<textarea/>` to collect the csv file. If you're uploading an attachment, different handling may be necessary (I'm not all that familiar with Python GAE or how it handles attachments).

Comment: Thanks!  This solved it, and your explanation was a lot easier for me to understand.

Comment: @August Flanagan I don't think the idea expressed in the sentence **The Python csv module operates on file-like objects, that is a file or something that behaves like a Python file. Hence, csv.reader() expects to get a file object as it's only required parameter.** being correct. Documentation says _"csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile. csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its next() method is called"_

Comment: @AugustFlanagan So it's clear that ``csv.reader(x)`` operates on an object ``x`` that is not necessarily a file-like object, the only requirement is that ``x`` must be an iterable and return strings when iterated.

Comment: @AugustFlanagan The more common practice is to pass a file-like object to ``csv.reader`` but the doc expresses clearly that it's not the obly possibility: _"— file objects and list objects are both suitable."_ - It happens that a string is iterable and that the iteration of a string returns objects whose type is ``str``, then a string can also be accepted by ``csv.reader()``; that doesn't mean that it is intersting to pass a string to ``csv.reader()``, that the reason why the doc deosn't precise it. But over-strictly speaking it would be correct if it was written ....

Comment: @AugustFlanagan ....: ``— file objects and list objects and strings objects are all suitable.`` But it wouldn't be a practical information, so it is not written like that. However we must not understand things with confusion. - That's why the following sentence is also false in my opinion: **Apparently, the csv module is falling-back when it does not understand the object and simply iterating it** : it doesn't fail, it perfectly handles a string as an iterable.

Comment: The post says "If you're uploading an attachment, different handling may be necessary".  I thought it worth mentioning how to do this for the benefit of those finding this post from Google like I did.  `uploaded_file = self.request.POST.get("file")` (notice the `POST` part; it won't work without this) and then `reader = csv.reader(uploaded_file.file)`.  `uploaded_file.file` is of type `cStringIO.StringO`, so it works in a similar way to the way that this post describes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `csv_file = self.request.POST.get("csv_import")` and *not* `csv_file = self.request.get("csv_import")`.

The second one just gives you a string as you mentioned in your original post.  But accessing via `self.request.POST.get` gives you a [cgi.FieldStorage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) object.

This means that you can call `csv_file.filename` to get the object’s filename and `csv_file.type` to get the mimetype.
Furthermore, if you access `csv_file.file`, it’s a StringO object (a read-only object from the [StringIO module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)), not just a string.  As ig0774 mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970785/328817), the StringIO module allows you to treat a string as a file.

Therefore, your code can simply be:

```
class CSVImport(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
     csv_file = self.request.POST.get('csv_import')
     fileReader = csv.reader(csv_file.file)
     for row in fileReader:
       # row is now a list containing all the column data in that row
       self.response.out.write(row)
```