# Upload and parse csv file with "universal newline" in python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

I'm uploading a csv/tsv file from a form in GAE, and I try to parse the file with python csv module.

Like describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970599/upload-and-parse-csv-file-with-google-app-engine), uploaded files in GAE are strings.
So I treat my uploaded *string* a file-like object :

```
file = self.request.get('catalog')
catalog = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(file),dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

But new lines in my files are not necessarily '\n' (thanks to excel..), and it generated an error :
*Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?*

Does anyone know how to use StringIO.StringIO to treat strings like files open in universal-newline?

Comment: According to the Python docs, StringIO's default mode is universal newline. Something stranger may be going on in your data file.

Comment: @Calvin _"According to the Python docs, StringIO's default mode is universal newline"_ I didn't find where the docs say that, could show it please ?

Comment: @eyquem It's been 2.5 years, so docs may have changed, but http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO says 'The newline argument works like that of TextIOWrapper' and TextIOWrapper says 'if newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled.' But then StringIO possibly contradicts this by saying 'The default is to do no newline translation.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
file = self.request.get('catalog')
file  = '\n'.join(file.splitlines())
catalog = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(file),dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

or as pointed out in the comments, `csv.reader()` supports input from a list, so:

```
file = self.request.get('catalog')
catalog = csv.reader(file.splitlines(),dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

or if in the future `request.get` supports read modes:

```
file = self.request.get('catalog', 'rU')
catalog = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(file),dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

Comment: I actually use .splitlines() but i work on very large files and it's not very fast. request.get() does not support read modes.

Comment: @greg : Then you're stuck. You can emulate it by doing .replace('\r\n', '\n') if that's the only line ending you need to change.

Comment: @greg I would take the speed hit and use `catalog = csv.reader(file.splitlines(),dialect=csv.excel_tab)`. (csv reader can accept a list of strings)

Comment: @Calvin : you're right, save the .join() and the StringIO is 1,6 times faster. thx

Comment: In csv files, you can have newline characters within a single "cell", as long as the cell is quoted.  The splitlines() technique would break in that scenario.

Answer (score 4):

The solution described [here](http://d4nt.com/parsing-large-csv-blobs-on-google-app-engine/) should work. By defining an iterator class as follows, which loads the blob 1MB at a time, splits the lines using .splitlines() and then feeds lines to the CSV reader one at a time, the newlines can be handled without having to load the whole file into memory.

```
class BlobIterator:
    """Because the python csv module doesn't like strange newline chars and
    the google blob reader cannot be told to open in universal mode, then
    we need to read blocks of the blob and 'fix' the newlines as we go"""

    def __init__(self, blob_reader):
        self.blob_reader = blob_reader
        self.last_line = ""
        self.line_num = 0
        self.lines = []
        self.buffer = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if not self.buffer or len(self.lines) == self.line_num + 1:
            self.buffer = self.blob_reader.read(1048576)  # 1MB buffer
            self.lines = self.buffer.splitlines()
            self.line_num = 0

            # Handle special case where our block just happens to end on a new line
            if self.buffer[-1:] == "\n" or self.buffer[-1:] == "\r":
                self.lines.append("")

        if not self.buffer:
            raise StopIteration

        if self.line_num == 0 and len(self.last_line) > 0:
            result = self.last_line + self.lines[self.line_num] + "\n"
        else:
            result = self.lines[self.line_num] + "\n"

        self.last_line = self.lines[self.line_num + 1]
        self.line_num += 1

        return result
```

Then call this like so:

```
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
blob_iterator = BlobIterator(blob_reader)
reader = csv.reader(blob_iterator)
```

Comment: In csv files, you can have newline characters within a single "cell", if the cell is quoted.  The splitlines() technique would break in that scenario.