# Access tab separated value content stored in a GAE blob, but using universal-newline mode or equivalent

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm trying to read the contents of a TSV file as part of a Google App Engine application.

I can read from a file fine by using:

```
f=csv.reader(open(matrixpath, "rU"),dialect='excel-tab')
```

However I now need to read the data from the blobstore using blobreader:

```
blob_key = ...
blobdata = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
f=csv.reader(blobdata,dialect='excel-tab')
```

([I've uploaded a copy of the entire code that I'm having this issue with here](http://pastebin.com/XpFaxEYi))

Without the rU argument I get a new-line in unquoted field error:

> Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

I would like to either fix my file so that I do not get this error, or emulate opening from the blobstore in a universal-newline mode?

My file is around 20MB, and [a cut down sample of it (that the script still fails on) can be found here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13381518/Marine-pollution-bulletin-matrix.txt).

Comment: have you tried with `f=csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(blobdata),dialect=csv.excel_tab)` ?

Comment: @Phil: If you are having a universal-newlines-related problem, posting a chunk of your file on the web doesn't help much -- does that chunk actually reproduce the problem? Please determine which line is causing the problem (count lines as you read it, trap the error, print #lines read) then show us repr(bad line plus two lines before and two lines after).

Comment: @systempuntoout - ah interesting... I thought the solution would involve StringIO and had experimented a little bit. I tried your suggestion and am now getting an _IndexError: list index out of range_ error that I don't get when I open the data as a file. Still, I guess the data is being read or I wouldn't be getting that error! If you submit this as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as one?

Comment: @John - yes that chunk does contain the offending line - I'll use your suggestion to try and determine which line is the bad one.

Comment: @Phil: Don't guess. Examine your data. Find out what your problem is. Don't play whack-a-mole.

Comment: @John - sorry, I should have been more clear - the new-line error occured at line 46, while the IndexError occurs later in the script at line 102 - hence my presumption that the file has been opened as the script has got that far. You are right though, I shouldn't be guessing!

Comment: @systempuntoout - the StringIO suggestion doesn't seem to work, it returns a csv.reader object but then when I try and `print` the first row I only get `[''] ` returned.

Comment: @Phil: (1) Nothing wrong around line 46 in sample file. Cannot reproduce the error, but result is of course nonsense (one byte per field, as expected). Please confirm that you have placed the exact contents of that sample file (obtained by e.g. `open('sample.tsv', 'rb').read()`) into a GAE blob and then you get the same error. (2) Error could mean a line with unbalanced or improperly quoted double-quotes but sample file looks OK quotewise. (3) Opening your file with 'rU' does make it work but so does the recommended 'rb' ... so we're back to the "blob == file?" question.

Comment: @John - apologies again, by line 46 I was referring to a line of a .py file ( `ulist=[row for row in f]` ) rather than the tsv data.

Comment: @John - yes it is that file that I have uploaded to the blobstore using the code from the blobstore GAE docs. If I try to serve that blobkey I get the same file served to the browser.

Comment: Did you see this similar question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341174/upload-and-parse-csv-file-with-universal-newline-in-python-on-google-app-engine/5341808#5341808  I think they ended up using `.splitlines()`, because `csv.reader` also accepts a list of strings.

Comment: @Phil: So where in the blob does the error occur???

Comment: @Calvin `f = csv.reader(blobdata.read().splitlines(),dialect=csv.excel_tab)` worked! Thank you very much for your input, and also thank you @John for all your assistance too.

Comment: @Phil ... but you still don't know what the problem was. You are still playing whack-a-mole.

Comment: @Phil ... and your problematic code used just `blobdata`, not `blobdata.read()` ... could that have been the cause?

Comment: @John - `f=csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(blobdata.read()),dialect=csv.excel_tab)` works too, thanks for suggesting that. I was forgetting that blobdata was like a file object when I was experimenting with StringIO.

Comment: Reading the whole blob into a StringIO is a poor solution if the blob will be big.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the error directly from the sample file. Can you?

Given `blob = open('sample-file.tsv', 'rb').read()`:

1. `reader = csv.reader(blob, dialect='excel-tab')` produces a zillion or so one-byte fields, as expected.
2. Substituting `StringIO.StringIO(blob)` or `blob.splitlines()` produces 50 rows each with about 10000 columns ... appears to be working correctly.

Unless you show (1) your blob uploading code (and URL of relevant docs) (2) your code that is getting the error on GAE, further assistance doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score -1):

From [Upload and parse csv file with "universal newline" in python on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341174/upload-and-parse-csv-file-with-universal-newline-in-python-on-google-app-engin) , the following answer worked for me:

`csv.reader(blob.open.read().splitlines())`

to read a mac formatted csv file on GNU/Linux.